# In Perl, what is the difference between use and require for loading a module?

Tags: perl, module, require

What is the difference between doing `use My::Module` and `require My::Module`?

Comment: @Ether: but this is the m.  One of them, anyway.

Comment: This may be easy to figure out on your own, but it's definitely a very good Perl question that beginners are prone to ask. I don't see why it should not be on stackoverflow. Where's the harm?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) function:

```
use ModuleName;
```

is equivalent to the following code using the [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) function:

```
BEGIN {
    require ModuleName;
    ModuleName->import;
}
```

The [`BEGIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#%26quot%3bBEGIN%2c-UNITCHECK%2c-CHECK%2c-INIT-and-END%26quot%3b) block causes this code to run as soon as the parser sees it.  The `require` loads the module or [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)s trying.  And then the `import` function of the module is called.  The `import` function may do all sorts of things, but it is common for it to load functions into the namespace that `use`d it (often with the [`Exporter`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html) module).

It is important to note that import will not be called in this case:

```
use ModuleName ();
```

In that case, it is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
    require ModuleName;
}
```

Comment: @Inshalla I like to leave a little wiggle room for my faulty memory.

Answer (score 18):

From [`perldoc -q` "difference between require and use"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-require-and-use?):

> `use Module` is like `require Module`, except that `use`
>
> 4.1: loads the module at compile time, not run-time.
>
> 4.2: imports symbols and semantics from that package to the current one.

Answer (score 10):

Perl comes with great documentation. Everyone would benefit from reading the entire documentation at least once every few months.

`C:\>` [`perldoc -f require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html)

> Otherwise `require` demands that a library file be
>   included if it hasn't already been
>   included. The file is included via the
>   do-FILE mechanism, which is
>   essentially just a variety of eval
>   with the caveat that lexical variables
>   in the invoking script will be
>   invisible to the included code. Has
>   semantics similar to the following
>   subroutine:

... etc. Similarly,

`C:\>` [`perldoc -f use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html)

> Imports some semantics into the
>   current package from the named module,
>   generally by aliasing certain
>   subroutine or variable names into your
>   package. It is exactly equivalent to
>
> ```
> BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
> ```
>
> except that Module must be a bareword.

... etc

There is also the [perlfaq entry](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-require-and-use?) although I think it is less informative than the above.

Comment: In addition to the wonderful `perldoc` command, you can access all of the same documentation through http://perldoc.perl.org

Comment: Ah. Your kbd tags make it harder to tell what's a link (as well as rendering not very prettily).

Answer (score 7):

`use` runs at compile time, and `require` runs at run time.

Comment: Don't forget the calling of `import`.

Comment: This is the answer they are looking for on Perl tests and job interviews. You need to memorize this!